# Vuejs get current year and following year

Tags: date, vue.js

I want to create a select option with current date and next year date using vuejs

here is my code

```
new Vue ({
  el: '.container',
  methods: {
    getCurrentYear() {
      return new Date().getFullYear();
    }
  }
});
<div class="container">
  <select id="dob">
    <option value="0">Year:</option>
    <option v-for="year in getCurrentYear()" :value="year">{{ year }}</option>
  </select>
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    selectedYear: ''
  },
  
  computed: {
    getYears () {
      let currentDate = new Date()
      let currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear()
      let nextyear = currentYear++
      return [currentYear, nextyear]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  Currently selected year: {{ selectedYear }} <br>

  <select v-model="selectedYear">
    <option value="">select year</option>
    <option
      v-for="(year, i) in getYears"
      :key="i"
      :value="year"
    >
      {{ year }}
    </option>
  </select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want use it in **`lang.js`** make like this:

```
copy_right: "All rights reserved © " + new Date().getFullYear() + " Your Company.",
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <footer>
      <p>CopyRight - {{currentYear}}</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      currentYear: new Date().getFullYear(), // 2020
    };
  }
};
</script>
```